# NullPointerException when using java WebServices

Tags: java, web-services

I have two classes, one being the client and one being the server. I am tyring to make a basic dictionary program but when I run glass fish and try to add two words I get a nullPointException, can someone help me out here :)

```
package dictionaryclient;

import dictionaryservice.DictionaryService;
import dictionaryservice.DictionaryServiceService;
import dictionaryservice.Book;

public class DictionaryClient  {

public static void main(String[] args){
  DictionaryClient client = new DictionaryClient();
  DictionaryServiceService service = new DictionaryServiceService();
  DictionaryService port = service.getDictionaryServicePort();

      port.addWord();

 }   
}
```

and

```
package dictionaryservice;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService
public class DictionaryService {

ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>();

@WebMethod
public void addWord(String title, String desc){
   map.put(title, desc);
   System.out.println("Succesfully Added");
}   
}
```

and am using glassfish tester to try to get this to work. I think the issue lies in the

```
port.addWord();
```

but I don't really know what to replace that with.

Its a basic dictionary web service where you can add or delete words.

Comment: Doesn't addWord take 2 string parameters? Did you check if port is null before calling addWord()? Did you mean to use the DictionaryClient that you've instantiated?

Comment: @kvr it does, you can input them in the server browsers provided by glass fish

Comment: I guess the exact error message would be helpful if we could look at it.